# ac-emacs-eclim-source not found

Tags: java, emacs, eclim

I am trying to setup emacs ide to use it with Java. I followed all the installation steps in [emacs-eclim repository](https://github.com/emacs-eclim/emacs-eclim/blob/master/README.md) and I can't setup the auto-completion mode.
If I copy the code that the installation manual says:

```
;; regular auto-complete initialization
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)

;; add the emacs-eclim source
(require 'ac-emacs-eclim-source)
(ac-emacs-eclim-config)
```

emacs tells me that the ac-emacs-eclim-source doesn't exist.
I tried to install the MELPA package ac-emacs-eclim, but emacs gives me errors when traying to autocomplete something. Yasnippet and auto-complete extensions work well, but I can't display for example if I put:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.
```

the methods of the object.
Any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me when I changed `(require 'ac-emacs-eclim-source)` to `(require 'ac-emacs-eclim)`. The first file is no longer in the source tree.